# How do I extract two things using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that has two things, which is the name of the petitioner and the advocate.

I wanna separate the petitioner names and the advocate names.

All petitioner names start with a number `(1-)` and the advocate name start with `Advocate-`.

> 1) RAM PRASAD\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Advocate- ADITYA PRASAD
>   MISHRA, A.P. MISHRA

This is another string.

> 1) KALAICHELVI
>
> Advocate - NOTICE ORDER R1 ONLY, -------------------------------, R1 - TAPAL RETURNED, NOT KNOWN
>
> 2) KALIMUTHU     3) RAMACHANDRA GOAUNER     4) SETHU AMMAL     5) SOMU
>   GOUNDER     6) SOMASUNDAR A GOUNDER     7) KARUNANITHI     8)
>   LALAITHAMMAL     9) JEGANNATHA GOUNDER

I tried doing this, `re.split(r'[ ]\xa0\xa0(?=[0-9]+\b)', s`) but works fine when the Adovate Name isn't present. How do I do this?

Comment: Are these in a file? Do they repeat?

Comment: In my DB, Yes the advocate name may occur below a petitioner's name. @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find two distinct things and plan to use regular expressions, it is almost always a good idea to use two distinct expressions instead of one. For example

```py
petitioner_re = re.compile(r"\d+\) ([A-Z ]+)")    # matches petitioners
advocate_re = re.compile(r"Advocate - ([^\n]+)")  # matches advocates
```

Given your example input, you can apply `re.finditer` for petitioners and `re.search` for advocates

```py
content = """
1) KALAICHELVI

Advocate - NOTICE ORDER R1 ONLY, -------------------------------, R1 - TAPAL RETURNED, NOT KNOWN

2) KALIMUTHU 3) RAMACHANDRA GOAUNER 4) SETHU AMMAL 5) SOMU GOUNDER 6) SOMASUNDAR A GOUNDER 7) KARUNANITHI 8) LALAITHAMMAL 9) JEGANNATHA GOUNDER
"""

petitioners = [p.group(1).strip() for p in petitioner_re.finditer(content)]
advocate = advocate_re.search(content)
```

Which gives the following result

```py
print(petitioners)
['KALAICHELVI', 'KALIMUTHU', 'RAMACHANDRA GOAUNER', 'SETHU AMMAL',
 'SOMU GOUNDER', 'SOMASUNDAR A GOUNDER', 'KARUNANITHI', 'LALAITHAMMAL', 
 'JEGANNATHA GOUNDER']
print(advocate)
'NOTICE ORDER R1 ONLY, -------------------------------, R1 - TAPAL RETURNED, NOT KNOWN'
```

If you have multiple advocates per entry and want to find all of them, they'll need to be fetched with `re.finditer` as well.